# Question on normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Let $x=(1 \, 2 \, 3 \, 4)$ and $y= (2 \, 4)$ be elements of $S_4$. Let $G= \langle x,y\rangle_{S_4}$, Let $H =\langle y\rangle_{S_4}$ and let $K=\langle x\rangle_{S_4}$. 
I have never seen this notation before, so I am confused on how to understand the elements in $G$, $H$, and $K$.
I also need to figure out whether $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Which I know means that $Hg=gH$. Then if that is true, what elements would be in $G/H$? If not, then the equivalence class of $H$ is not congruent relation for the group operation of $G$..just now just how to show this.

Comment: The notation $\langle x\rangle_G$ refers to the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing the element $x$. So $H$ is the smallest subset of $S_4$ containing the $2$-cycle $(24)$; in particular, as a set, $H = \{1, (24)\}$.

Comment: I changed $<x,y>$ to $\langle x,y\rangle$.  That is standard usage.

Comment: It doesn't just mean $Hg=gH$; it means that that holds for EVERY value of $g$.

Comment: And I took the liberty of adding some thin spaces in between the numbers in the cycles. Compare $(1 2)$ and $(1\,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, to determine whether $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, you need to determine whether for each $g \in G$, $gH=Hg$. Try this. Pick some element of $G$, say $(1,2,3,4)$ and some element $h \in H$, say $h=(2,4)$ and see whether $ghg^{-1} \in H$.

Here is another way to show a subgroup is normal. $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ if and only if there exists some homomorphism $f$ and some group $K$ so that $f: G \to K$ and $H$ is the kernel of $f$.

In this case, the first method will be more useful.